# SSIS ETL does not pick the file from Share point when it execute through SQL Agent job

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have created one SSIS packages, which pick the file from the Share point document library. its work successfully, once it execute through the VS project application.

But when i create a job in SQL Server Agent for this package then it does not pick the file and job getting fail.

Just for more update, SQL Server has been install in Cluster mode and using BIDS 2012 with SQl Server 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the login credential detail to SSIS package for picking the file from the share point document library,

for fixing this issue, You have to use  "Net use" command like this [link](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_use.mspx?mfr=true) and create a one .bat file, and that .bat file called in SSIS package "Execute Process Task" tool.

By this command you can create the network map drive and pass the User name and password on the Share point document library.

Answer (score 1):

Your "SQL Server Agent" (or the user you choose in the "Run as" dropdownlist of the Job properties) must have the rights on the SharePoint Server.

It works when you're running the package from VS because when you run a package in VS it's running with your own user rights (and you have rights on the SharePoint server).

Comment: I have defined the Proxy, but its still not working,